# Does Euron have "magical" support that helped him build 1000 ships?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In the space between S06E10 and S07E01,Euron has built up a fleet of 1000 ships. Considering the amount of wood, man-hours, real estate and time this *should* take, is it safe to speculate that magic was involved? A friend sent me [this](http://mashable.com/2017/07/22/euron-greyjoy-1000-ships-game-of-thrones-plot-hole), describing how infeasible it is.

Comment: I think this is a "we don't know yet". In the books, Euron has picked up at least one magical trinket (which he's not able to use properly) on his travels, and may have more, but there's no hint yet that these exist in the TV version; also there are few other things in the show that could be explained by magic - or which might just be artistic license: e.g. how his fleet 'sneaked up' in S07E02, the number and rate of fire projectiles in that battle, and how he just appeared on that bridge opposite Balon (which is also a mystery in the books)

Comment: [Not a plothole.](http://imgur.com/a/L7zDu) I'm voting to close this due to our Future works policy. This will likely be answered in a later episode.

Comment: He did not even need 1000 ships. Yara and Theon did not take the whole fleet when they ran. He could just be pursing them in his existing ships. I think his quote was something more on the lines of "build me 1000 ships and I will give you the seven kingdoms" in season 6.

Comment: @Skooba Actually he promised them the world.

Comment: @Jedi I have two questions for you that I think you should integrate in to your question to strengthen it: How much time do you think has passed for Euron since he asked for the 1000 ships, and what makes you think all 1000 ships have been built yet?

Comment: Supposing it is feasible to build 1,000 ships in a matter of months, the follow up question is why the Iron Isles don't permanently maintain a larger fleet of ships, which would be put to good use raiding & controlling the shipping lanes?